# columns and type attributes are not functioning as expected in the @CollectionId annotation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am currently working with **Hibernate-core ORM** version 6.3.1.Final. It appears that when using collections in a class, the `columns` and `type` attributes do not seem to function as expected within the `@CollectionId` annotation.

```
package org.hibernateJavaBrains;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionId;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "userDetails")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userId;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ADDRESS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_gen", strategy = "sequence")
    @CollectionId(columns = @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID"),type = @Type(type = "long"),generator = "sequence_gen")
    private Collection<Address> listOfAddress = new ArrayList<Address>();


    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public Collection<Address> getListOfAddress() {
        return listOfAddress;
    }

    public void setListOfAddress(Collection<Address> listOfAddress) {
        this.listOfAddress = listOfAddress;
    }
}
```

In the part

```
 @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ADDRESS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_gen", strategy = "sequence")
    @CollectionId(columns = @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID"),type = @Type(type = "long"),generator = "sequence_gen")
    private Collection<Address> listOfAddress = new ArrayList<Address>();
```

give me

Cannot resolve method 'columns'

Cannot resolve method 'type'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVjIJ.png)

> Is it possible to know the cause of this error and what is its solution if I want to create an `Address_id` column in `userdetails_listofaddress` table?

I tried to change `columns` to `column` and it did not give an error.
but when change `type` to `value` The `type` value of `long` will give an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4EJK.png)

I was following the explanation in this video :

[Hibernate Tutorial 11 - Configuring Collections and Adding Keys - java brains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kk207HAym_I&list=PL4AFF701184976B25&index=16)